# Postgresql: dblink in Stored Functions from local to remote database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I check below link which I used and running perfectly. But I want to opposite this things.

[Postgresql: dblink in Stored Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148534/postgresql-dblink-in-stored-functions)

My scenario: Two databases are there. I want to copy one table data from local to remote database. I used dblink for this used but I am confused how to use dblink to store the data?

Local database name:  localdatabase

Remote Database name: remotedatabase

Can any one suggest me how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically the approach described in the answer there will work for you.  You have to replace dblink() with dblink_exec(), which is to be used for SQL statements not returning rows (like `INSERT` in your case).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, But I want to insert all the data from local to remote database. And at that Time I am on local side and want to transfer all the data using dblink. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Something like the lines below should work:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydb user=postgres password=mypasswd');
-- change the connection string to your taste

SELECT dblink_exec('INSERT INTO test (some_text) VALUES (''Text go here'');');
```

Where `test` is a table in the remote database with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id serial
    , some_text text
);
```

After running `dblink_exec()`, you can check the results in the remote database (or locally, using `dblink()`, like in the example below).

```
SELECT * FROM dblink('SELECT id, some_text FROM test') AS d(id integer, some_text text);
 id |  some_text
----+--------------
  1 | Text go here
(1 row)
```

You can wrap your `dblink_exec` call in a function as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dblink_test_update(val text, id integer) RETURNS text AS
$body$
SELECT dblink_exec('UPDATE torles.test SET some_text=' || quote_literal($1) || ' WHERE id = ' || $2);
$body$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

As you can see, you can even build your query string dynamically.  *(Not that I advocate this approach, since you have to be careful not to introduce a SQL injection vulnerability into your system this way.)*

Since `dblink_exec` returns with a text message about what it did, you have to define your function as `RETURNS text` unless there are other value-returning statements after the `dblink_exec` call.

Comment: Is it possible to update query with procedure with the help of dblink?